# Load different ApplicationContext based on URL server name

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

My application on the server could be visited by two servername ,now I want to load different applicationcontext.xml  by different servername. how do I could do it ?It's a Java EE by spring!!

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "visited by two servername" you mean a different HTTP `hostname` but mapped to the same Java EE server instance.

e.g. server1.acme.com and server2.acme.com

One option is to install the application twice (two separate EAR/WAR files) and configure which applicationcontext.xml you wish to use as part of your build process. This has the advantage of you being able to assign a separate context root if you wanted. You can then configure your Java EE server (e.g. the apache server component) to map a `hostname` to a particular application context root.

Option two is to install only one EAR/WAR that contains all of your spring beans for both instances, and assign unique bean names for those beans that shouldn't be shared. This has the advantage of reduce memory footprint as you're only loading one application and sharing some of the Spring beans. Your web `Controller`s will have to be aware of which service beans to call based on the `hostname` which should you can get by calling [ServletRequest.getRemoteHost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost%28%29)

I'm sure there are other techniques you could employ. These are just two that came to mind.

Comment: the application would load different resource according to different hostname,so I just get hostname then judge it to show different images or words!! thanks all the same!!